# How to access USB ports in java

Tags: java, usb, rxtx

I'm trying to write a java application that accesses the usb ports to read from and write to a device connected through usb.  The problem I face is that I don't know what exactly to use in java to do such a thing.  I searched online and found something called `JUSB` but all the posts seem fairly old.

Currently I'm using the `RXTX` libraries but I sometimes run into some sync error.  When I use C# to do the equivalent it requires far less code and I don't face any of the same sync error.

My question is, **is there anything built into the latest version of the JRE I can use to access the usb ports** (*that is just as easy as the equivalent C# code*)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is nothing equivalent to C#'s USB support in Java. Both jUSB and Java-USB are severely out-of-date and likely unusable for any serious application development.

If you want to implement a cross-platform USB application, really your best bet is to write an abstract [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) interface that talks to Linux, Mac and Windows native libraries that you'll have to write yourself. I'd look at [LibUSB](http://www.libusb.org/) to handle Mac and Linux. Windows, as you've seen, is pretty straightforward. I just came off a year-long project that did just this, and unfortunately this is the only serious cross-platform solution. If you don't have to implement on Windows and your needs are limited, you may get by with one of the older Java libs (jUSB or Java-USB). Anything that needs to deploy on Win32/Win64 will need a native component.

Comment: What about [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/)? Seems to be a good alternative. I am not related to this development.

Answer (score 28):

Been using usb4java for a year on cross platfom (Linux and Windows) and it works great.

See:

http://usb4java.org/

They are very active and have a very good javax USB front.

Answer (score 8):

See the [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) or [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/) libraries.

Comment: Java-USB is Linux-only. If that's all you need, it may work out, although it doesn't appear to have been updated in a while.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to have a look at usb4java - http://usb4java.org/index.html it appears to support Windows, Linux and Mac OS's and appears to be reasonably current at the time of posting. Is unfortunately under the LGPL so may not be suitable for commercial development.

Comment: Linking with LGPL libraries should not be an issue, if you are going to only use their APIs in your code (and you have a non LGPL license). GPL licensed libraries are copyleft licenses, forcing your code's license also to be GPL license, regardless of what license you have used.

Answer (score 2):

The [Java Communications API](http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/). This should provide similar functionality to the C# [System.IO.Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.aspx) namespace.

Comment: System.IO.Ports is for Serial communications unless the OP is implying a serial-to-usb interface?!

Comment: Agreed -- System.IO.Ports has no USB interfaces, is only for Com Ports.

Comment: If you're USB device is exposed on a COM port then you can use System.IO.Ports.

Comment: Taylor: Have you tried it? Does it actually work?

Comment: Yes, I have an application that already does this that I use every day. The USB device is an encoder for magnetic stripe cards.

Comment: So that's a USB to serial cable? unless the USB driver is using serial emulation...interesting...never heard of that angle before...I have used a magnetic card reader which is a serial interface, using a usb cable... but it does not work (the limitation on the driver itself plus the cable was cheap)

Comment: It is using a USB-RS232 serial COM port interface, but there is no actual USB to serial cable connected to the devices USB cable.

Answer (score -2):

If you're on a mac, USB's can be accessed with the /Volumes/ directory.

Example:

You want to write to a file in "Drive", so the filepath would be:

`/Volumes/Drive/file.whatever`

Not sure how it's accomplished on other platforms, but this is the simplest way I've found on a mac

Comment: Only drives can be accessed. But there are a lot more USB devices