# simple program of java to comminucate with usb port

Tags: java, c++, usb

Currently I am accessing usb port using dll file in C++.I want to achieve same functionality in core java(Not using JNI).Can some one provide me any simple tatourial for how to read data from USB port.
I am using windows 7 for my development and NetBeans IDE.

I had seen [How to access USB ports in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121508/how-to-access-usb-ports-in-java) but it seems to be little outdated.

Comment: I had tried RxTx But of no use.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need some technical background about USB, hardware and software. With USB there are no Rx/Tx lines, just *"one line"* over two wires with differential electric transmission.

About your initial question the response is that you cannot write a pure Java implementation. You have to interact with the driver, which is written in C, so you will have to use JNI.

Comment: you are saying its not possible without using dll on windows machine?

Comment: No, it's not possible, but it's not only on Windows, the same applies for other operating systems like, Linux, etc.