# Whats the easiest way to connect to a serial port in Java on a mac?

Tags: java, macos, serial-port

I've tried RXTX and jSSC, neither of which worked on my system.
I've also tried running shell commands with Runtime.exec():

```
Runtime.getRuntiime().exec("cat /dev/cu./dev/cu.usbserial-AM01VF5Z")
```

but this only works some of the time

any thoughts?

Comment: "but this only works some of the time" can you elaborate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access USB ports in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121508/how-to-access-usb-ports-in-java)