# Trying to communicate to a USB port/Device in Java on Mac

Tags: java, api, unix, network-programming

I have a basic understanding of network programming but i have never had anything to do with USB ports.

This is what i am trying to achieve

**I need to write a program in Java, to communicate to a device which is connected to USB port and then later send commands.**

I tried terminal as follows earlier but it didn't quite work

```
ls -l /dev/tty.*
screen /dev/tty.usbserrial-FTYRDSX7 9600
```

The above didn't work out.

So if someone can just guide with what Java classes i should be looking into and if there are any APIs that should help me get started

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access USB ports in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121508/how-to-access-usb-ports-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're required to build it from the ground up, use a library such as [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/) (also [here](https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java)).  Trying to manage it as a block device and interpreting whatever protocols etc., etc is not worth the effort unless there something very unique to your problem.

Comment: So the module is a part of a machine, and i want to run a series of test on it, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

So i ended up using [jssc](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wikis/jSSC_Start_Working.wiki) which is much easier to use with strait forward syntax and methods